# Echo a mysql query result in the color red

Tags: php, mysql

The line `NOT DINE WITH` I would like to output in red, any ideas on how to do this please?

```
<?php
$res22 = mysql_query($query22);
while ($row22 = mysql_fetch_array($res22, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
?><OPTION VALUE="<?php
echo $row22['member_id'];?>">
<?php echo $row22['full_name']; ?> 

<font color=#ff0000> 
<?php if ($row22['ndw'] == "yes")
echo "  *-* NOT DINE WITH *-*"; ?></font> -

<?php echo $row22['member_id']; ?>
<?php if ($row22['joined_online'] == "yes")
echo " *JOL* "; ?> 
<?php if ($row22['email']== '')
echo " *NOEM*";
?>
<?php echo " Invites "; ?>
<?php echo $row22['invited']; ?>
<?php echo " Attended "; ?>
<?php echo $row22['attended']; ?>
</option><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: please update your full code

Comment: The font tag is deprecated. I recommend using CSS.

Comment: Firstly it would be better to put a span around your `NOT DINE WITH` text, and use CSS to change it, the <font> tags are deprecated

Comment: It looks like you're trying to style an option tag?  If so then browser support for this is very limited.

Comment: The rest of the code has been fine for years now, I still use font elsewhere with no problem.

Comment: PeteAIK - you may be right as I swore it was working a couple of days back and I possibly used chrome to view instead of Firefox

Comment: I just tried in chrome no go also.

Comment: I am using the option tag.

Comment: @newphper, your best bet would be to put a class with that option tag, and change the font color to red, but then everything in that option element will be red. You can't do separate colors in an option tag. Unless you modify it all with JavaScript.

Comment: I am not familiar with JavaScript and guess I will have to learn some, thank you Kacey

Answer (score 3):

try

```
echo "<span style='color:ff0000;'>  *-* NOT DINE WITH *-*<span>";
```

Comment: Thank you, but no go. I have tried many ways but the right way before posting this question as a last resort.

Comment: then check you have right on if ($row22['ndw'] == "yes")

Comment: It displays in black, the logic is working fine if that is what you mean

Comment: try echo $row22['ndw'] and match in if() what you get in echo

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I wrote up for you that will require some JavaScript to select the proper option. I'm assuming you're using a form to select people from a database?

```
<?php

$res22 = mysql_query($query22);

echo "<ul>";

while ($row22 = mysql_fetch_array($res22, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $member_id = $row22['member_id'];
    $full_name = $row22['full_name'];
    $ndw = $row22['ndw'];
    $joined_online = $row22['joined_online'];
    $email = $row22['email'];
    $invited = $row22['invited'];
    $attended = $row22['attended'];

    $class = $ndw == "yes" ? 'class="ndw"' : '';

    echo '<li ' . $class . ' id="' . $member_id . '">';
    echo "{$full_name} - ";
    echo $ndw == "yes" ? "<span>*-* NOT DINE WITH *-*</span> " : "";
    echo "{$member_id} - ";
    echo $joined_online == "yes" ? "*JOL* " : "";
    echo empty($email) ? "*NOEM* " : "";
    echo "Invites: {$invited}, ";
    echo "Attended: {$attended}";
    echo '</li>';
}

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Here's a fiddle I put together that shows how it would look, and work: http://jsfiddle.net/d4r6V/. It uses jQuery. You'll have to do a lot of modifying to make it work in a form, etc., but hopefully it can get you started.

Comment: Thank you Kacey, much appreciated. It is midnight here and I will have a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML 4.1 and 5.1 specification it's not allowed to have any tag inside an option tag.

```
<!ELEMENT OPTION - O (#PCDATA)         -- selectable choice -->
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION

```
Content model:
If the element has a label attribute and a value attribute: Empty.
If the element has a label attribute but no value attribute: Text.
If the element has no label attribute: Text that is not inter-element whitespace.
```

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-option-element

The font tag was completely removed in HTML5 and must not be used. But I'd guess most browsers still support it.

http:// www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html <- Not enough reputation to provide you that useful link...

So it's not possible to style only a part of an option text. You could however style the complete option field. The font element outside the select element might still render the desired result. See example below:

```
<style>
    option.red_background {background-color: red;}
    option.red_text {color: red;}
</style>
<select>
    <option value="0">
        <?php echo 'full_name'; ?>
        <font color=#ff0000>
            <?php echo "  *-* NOT DINE WITH *-*"; ?>
        </font>
    </option>
        <?php
        if ($row22['ndw'] === 'yes') {
            echo '<option class="red_text" value="1">';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="1">';
        }
        ?>
        <?php echo 'full_name'; ?>
        <?php echo "  *-* NOT DINE WITH *-*"; ?>
    </option>
    <option class="red_background" value="2">
        <?php echo 'full_name'; ?>
        <?php echo "  *-* NOT DINE WITH *-*"; ?>
    </option>
</select>
<font color=#ff0000>
    <?php echo "  *-* NOT DINE WITH *-*"; ?>
</font>
```

Comment: I apologise if I have not made the problem quite clear. We can do a search for members that meet a certain criteria. When the result set is displayed, we just want any member that has the value *-* NOT DINE WITH *-* displayed in the color red. We need them to stand out form the rest so we can check their member file to see whom they do not wish to dine with. They results work fine but they are all in black. Even if we could make *-* NOT DINE WITH *-* BOLD it would help it stand out for us.

Comment: I've omitted all your variables so that I don't had to initialize them before testing my code. Now I updated (added the condition) my answer to clarify what my intention was. Instead of highlighting only NOT DINE WITH highlight the whole option element. And it indeed stands out from the rest.